# uibutton does not return initial data

Tags: swift, xcode, button, delegates, geocode

**strong text**i had two problem:

1 problem) when I press the button, it should return my position data, but it doesn't return it and I think I understand why, but I can't solve it. the problem is the logic contained in the locationManager func.

2 problem)

I retrieve the weather info by inserting latitude and longitude.
I added another "textField" to do the search with the city, but it doesn't update me anything and I think it's a delegate problem, but I can't get out of it.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchLat: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchLong: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Velocitàvento: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var direzioneVento: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchCity: UITextField!
    
    var weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        
        weatherManager.delegate = self
        searchLat.delegate = self
        searchLong.delegate = self
        
        /* if (searchLat.text != "") && (searchLong.text != "") {
         getNameCity()
         } */
        //  getNameCity()
        
        
        //PROVA
        /*  if(searchCity.text != "") {  //PROVA
         getCoordinate()
         }
         getCoordinate() */
        
        
    }
    @IBAction func locationPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
}

// scrivendo questo XCODE  crea un divisorio che evindezia le varie sezioni.
//MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate

extension WeatherViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        searchLat.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        searchLong.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        searchCity.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        
        
        /*   if searchLat.text != "" || searchLong.text != "" {
         // print(searchLat.text!)
         
         //PROVA
         } */
        
        if(searchCity.text != "") {  //PROVA
            getCoordinate()
        }
        
        /*   if searchLat.text != String("0.0") && searchLong.text != String("0.0") {
         searchCity.text = ""
         }
         if searchCity.text != ""  {
         searchLat.text = ""
         searchLat.text = ""
         } */
    }
    
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        
        searchLat.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        searchLong.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        searchCity.endEditing(true) //all'invio sparisce tastiera
        
        
        if (searchLat.text != "" && searchLong.text != "") {
            //  print(searchLat.text!)
            // print(searchLong.text!)
            return true
        } else if (searchCity.text != "") {
            //  print(searchLat.text!)
            // print(searchLong.text!)
            return true
        } else if (searchLat.text == "" && searchLong.text != "") {
            //  print(searchLong.text!)
            return true
        } else if (searchLat.text != "" && searchLong.text == "") {
            //  print(searchLat.text!)
            return true
        }else {
            searchLat.placeholder = "ins. lat."
            searchLong.placeholder = "ins. long."
            searchCity.placeholder = "ins. Città."
            return true
        }
        
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // viene fatta validazione
        if (searchLat.text != "" || searchLong.text != "") {
            return true
        } else if (searchCity.text != "") {
            //  print(searchLat.text!)
            // print(searchLong.text!)
            return true
        } else if (searchLat.text != "" && searchLong.text == "") {
            //searchLat.placeholder = "inserisci lat."
            searchLong.placeholder = "inserisci long."
            return (searchLat.text != nil) == true
        } else if (searchLat.text == "" && searchLong.text != "") {
            searchLat.placeholder = "inserisci lat."
            return (searchLong.text != nil) == true
            //searchLong.placeholder = "inserisci long."
        }else {
            searchLat.placeholder = "inserisci lat."
            searchLong.placeholder = "inserisci long."
            return true
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //all'invio ripulisce i valori
        
        /* new */
        let latitudine = searchLat.text
        let longitudine = searchLong.text
        let city = searchCity.text
        
        if (latitudine != "") && (longitudine != "") {
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(lat:String(latitudine!), long:String(longitudine!))
        }
        
        if city != "" {
            searchCity.text = ""
        }
        /*   if (searchLat.text != "" && searchLong.text != ""){
         print(searchLat.text!)
         print(searchLong.text!)
         
         searchLat.text = ""
         searchLong.text = ""
         } */
    }
}

//MARK: - WeatherManagerDelegate


extension WeatherViewController: WeatherManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager, weather: WeatherModel) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            //  if (self.searchLat.text != "" && self.searchLong.text != "") {
            self.getNameCity()
            self.getCoordinate()
            self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString
            self.Velocitàvento.text = String(weather.velovento)
            self.direzioneVento.text = String(weather.direzionevento)
            self.conditionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: weather.conditionName)
            
            
            // }
            /* else {
             self.getCoordinate()
             self.temperatureLabel.text = weather.temperatureString
             self.Velocitàvento.text = String(weather.velovento)
             self.direzioneVento.text = String(weather.direzionevento)
             self.conditionImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: weather.conditionName)
             } */
            
            //PROVA
            /*  if(self.searchCity.text != nil) {  //PROVA
             self.getCoordinate()
             } */
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}

//MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let latid = location.coordinate.latitude
            let longit = location.coordinate.longitude
            
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(latid: Double(latid), longit: Double(longit))
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: latid, longitude: longit)
                geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                    
                    // Place details
                    var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                    placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                    
                    // Locality
                    if let locality = placeMark.locality {
                        self.cityLabel.text = "Città: \(locality)"
                    }
                    
                }) /*new*/
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
    func getNameCity() {
        /*new*/
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let uno = Double(self.searchLat.text!) ?? 0.0
            let due = Double(self.searchLong.text!) ?? 0.0
            
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: uno, longitude: due)
            geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                
                // Place details
                var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                
                // Locality
                if let locality = placeMark.locality {
                    self.cityLabel.text = "Città: \(locality)"
                }
                
            }) /*new*/
            
        }
    }
    
    func getCoordinate() {
        /*new*/
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(self.searchCity.text ?? "") { placemarks, error in
                let placemark = placemarks?.first
                let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
                print("Lat: \(lat ?? 0.0), lon: \(lon ?? 0.0)")
                
                
                //**
                let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat ?? 0.0, longitude: lon ?? 0.0)
                geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                    
                    // Place details
                    var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
                    placeMark = placemarks?[0]
                    
                    // Locality
                    if let locality = placeMark.locality {
                        self.cityLabel.text = "Città: \(locality)"
                    }
                    
                })
                //**
                
                if self.searchLat.text != String("0.0") && self.searchLong.text != String("0.0") {
                    self.searchCity.text = ""
                }
                if self.searchCity.text != ""  {
                    self.searchLat.text = ""
                    self.searchLat.text = ""
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

protocol WeatherManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdateWeather(_ weatherManager: WeatherManager, weather: WeatherModel)
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}

struct WeatherManager {
    let weatherURL = "https://api.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?&current_weather=true&hourly=rain&hourly=temperature_2m"
    
    var delegate: WeatherManagerDelegate?
    
    func fetchWeather (lat:String, long: String){
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&latitude=\(lat)&longitude=\(long)"
        
        if lat != "" && long != "" {
            performRequest(with: urlString)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchWeather (latid: CLLocationDegrees, longit: CLLocationDegrees) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&latitude=\(latid)&longitude=\(longit)"
        performRequest(with: urlString)
    }
    
    //creo la connessione per recuperare le info
    func performRequest(with urlString: String) {
        //1 create URL
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            //2 create a URLSession
            
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            
            //3 Give the session a task
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }
                
                if let safeData = data {
                    //non vogliamo il file come datastring, ma lo trasformiamo in oggetto swift
                    
                    if let weather = parseJSON(safeData) {
                        delegate?.didUpdateWeather(self,weather: weather)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            //4 Start the task
            
            task.resume()
        }
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ weatherData: Data) -> WeatherModel?{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: weatherData)
            //print(decodedData.hourly.time[0])
            let id = decodedData.current_weather.weathercode
            let temp = decodedData.current_weather.temperature
            let latitudine = decodedData.latitude
            let longitudine = decodedData.longitude
            let velocitavento = decodedData.current_weather.windspeed
            let direzionevento = decodedData.current_weather.winddirection
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(meteocode: id, latitudine: latitudine, longitudine: longitudine, temperatura: temp, windspeed: velocitavento, winddirection: direzionevento)
            
            return weather
            
            
        } catch {
            delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
            return nil
        }       
    }    
}
```

Comment: You say "when I press the button, it should return my position data..." What button? the one connected to the `locationPressed()` IBAction in your `WeatherViewController`? What does "it should return my position data" mean? Return it to whom, and how? Button IBAction functions don't return a value.

Comment: You posted a GREAT DEAL of code (299 lines) with almost no explanation of what it's supposed to do. Reading code in a Stack Overflow page is really hard. You need to provide a lot more information about your code and how it's supposed to work if you want us to help.

Comment: when I press "searchPressed" it must return the weather info which I then insert in the view. the info is retrieved from the API. I have three textfields, if I enter latitude and longitude and then press the search button, it values the fields correctly. if I enter the name of the city I do not poppola the leaders because it does not go to update. I think the problem is the delegate managed in the struct that I am now attaching. this is because when the button is pressed, the info is retrieved from the API.

Comment: in the case of the city instead, I insert the name of the city and then convert everything into Lat. and long. to populate the field of the city, but there is no other info that I can not retrieve from the api.
hope i was clearer, let me know if anything is unclear thanks.